# I want to use two or more button having different functionalities.How to do it?

Tags: button, assembly, pic

I want to make 2 or more buttons wait for pressing.

For example, increment or decrement the value in the 7 segment-display.
Button1 increments and Button2 decrements the value.
For the below code , i can decrement or increment it , but cannot do both of them.

for  one button  , i do it in such a way that:

PROCESS2:                           ;the functionality of SW09 & SW11

....................

```
BTFSC   PORTB,7       This line is to understand whether we pressed button or not.        

GOTO    PROCESS2      We cant go below until the button pressed 

CALL    UP        ;Up increments the value which will be shown in the 7-segment-display.

BTFSS   PORTB,7

GOTO    $-1
```

Then how to do it for more than one buttons.What is the algorithm ? What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its mandatory to use assembler, but in C this is pretty simple.

Assuming BUTTON1 & BUTTON2 are defined somewhere else as an input pin and that they have pull-ups, you can try:

```c
void checkIncrement(void)
{
    if (BUTTON1 == 0) {
        while (BUTTON1 == 0) DelayMs(1); // software debounce
        increment(); // call the increment function
    }
}

void checkDecrement(void)
{
    if (BUTTON2 == 0) {
        while (BUTTON2 == 0) DelayMs(1);
        decrement();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // your main loop
    while (1)
    {
        checkIncrement();
        checkDecrement();
        
        // do something else if none of the buttons are pressed
    }
}
```

If assembler is necessary, you can try compiling and seeing the assembler listings to give an idea of how it has been done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PIC assembly but I remember about MCS51 assembly, maybe this is not according to your question but can be used as a reference.

I assume the button work as active low (when the button is pressed then the port of button will be pull low OR port of button will be connected to ground when button pressed).

```
    button1 EQU P1.0 ; Port1 bit0 as button1 (input)
    button2 EQU P1.1 ; Port1 bit1 as button2 (input)
    led     EQU P2   ; Port2 bit 0 until 8 as led (output)

    ORG  00H      
    mov A,#7FH       ; init led value 7FH = 0111 1111B
    mov R0,A
main:

btn1sts:
    jb button1, btn2sts  ;if button1 not pressed then check button2 status
    jnb button1, $       ;wait until button 1 is released
    inc R0               ;A value only increases after the button1 is released.
    sjmp process:

btn2sts:
    jb button2, btn1sts  ;if button2 not pressed then check button1 status
    jnb button2, $       ;wait until button 2 is released
    dec R0               ;A value only decreases after the button2 is released.

process:
   mov A, R0        
   mov led, A       ;show A value in P2 (led).
   ljmp main:       ;goto main
```